# MongoDB find with key that starts with a string pattern

Tags: php, mongodb, select

I'm trying to fetch a mongodb data using PHP.
My Data is in the following format:

```
$document = $collection->findOne(
                     array('_id' => 'set1'), 
                     array('projection' => array('_id' => 1,'data'=>1))
            ); 
Result:

{
  "_id": "set1",
  "data": {
    "IND": {
      "2015-01": 0.6753404,
      "2015-02": 1.0502269,
      "2015-03": 1.0902269
    },
    "AUS": {
      "2015-01": 0.6753404,
      "2015-02": 1.0502269,
      "2015-03": 1.0902269
    },
    "IND_123": {
      "2015-01": 0.6753404,
      "2015-02": 1.0502269,
      "2015-03": 1.0902269
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the output such that the result only has "IND" and "IND_123".

Is there a way to write the projection such that the result only provides "IND*"
The following provides only "IND"

```
$document = $collection->findOne(
                         array('_id' => 'set1'), 
                         array('projection' => array('_id' => 1,'data.IND'=>1))
                );
```

Comment: could you please let us know the column name where `IND` or `IND_123` getting stored

Comment: A single document contains the "data" field. The "data" field contains IND, IND_123, IND_232, IND_4534, AUS, AUS_454, AUS_432 etc.
These are countries and their subnationals (states or provinces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using an aggregation pipeline, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "set1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      data: {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$data"
            },
            "as": "item",
            "cond": {
              "$regexMatch": {
                "input": "$$item.k",
                "regex": "IND.*"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P8s2NOyslAW).
Here, we match the required document using `$match`. Then we, recompute the `data` field in `$project`, we first convert the `data` object to an array using `$objectToArray`, and filter all keys matching the pattern `IND.*` using `$filter`. Finally, we convert the filtered array back to an object using `$arrayToObject`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this guides me on a new approach. One question - In terms of performance, does this query fetch the entire result and then filters out the necessary data - or - it only fetches the necessary data?

Comment: It fetches only the required documents, specified according to the filter in `$match`, and then filters, out the data object